# Dockerfile maven plugin not working

Tags: maven, docker

I am using 'dockerfile-maven-plugin' to build & push dockerfiles in maven as docker-maven-plugin is deprecated. However, when I use 'docker-maven plugin', images are build but on using 'dockerfile-maven-plugin' I get below error:

> --- com.spotify.docker.client.exceptions.DockerException: pull access denied for imagename, repository does not exist or may require 'docker
>   login'

I did docker login, added user to group, installed latest docker version (thinking it requires latest), updated `settings.xml` with my credentials but still the same error. Any help regarding this will be very helpful.

Comment: Why do you say docker-maven-plugin is deprecated? It's 4 years after this question was posted and there seems to be recent development activity (https://github.com/fabric8io/docker-maven-plugin). Were you instead referring to dockerfile-maven (https://github.com/spotify/dockerfile-maven)?

Answer (score 3):

```
   <configuration>
        <repository>dockerregistry.xxx.dev/xxxx</repository>
        <tag>O-SANPSHOT</tag>
        <pullNewerImage>false</pullNewerImage>               
   </configuration>
```

Add `<pullNewerImage>false</pullNewerImage>` inside configuration tag. generally it will try to pull the image from repository. Because of the your local image won't be recognized. This solved my issue.

For more information: [read this thread](https://github.com/spotify/dockerfile-maven/issues/55)

Answer (score 2):

Had the same issue, but only when my Dockerfile was based on a private image.

Ugly workaround that worked for me is to pull base image using `docker pull <imagename>` and then add flag `-Ddockerfile.build.pullNewerImage=false` to your maven command so it use the image from cache.

Comment: Thanks that's the problem we have an internal private repo and I kept getting this error.